# Why won't FancyBox work?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a client that I am making an e-commerce website for, and I am trying to use FancyBox to better the design. I have been at this for nearly three days now, and I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I have read/watched tutorials, copied and pasted code, done everything that I can think to do to get it to run. This isn't the issue that I've seen time and time again on here about one image showing up right, or something not being linked in correctly. NOTHING is happening. I even switched staging servers when the initial one unexpectedly reset its permissions. The server also regressed to not being able to read links when they were enclosed within double quotes, so after switching to single quotes, I know they are being connected. All images, CSS, Javascript, jQuery, and plugins are now being linked in correctly. The issue now is whether FancyBox is being called at all, and/or if the Javascript is addressing things correctly. Firebug shows no errors. I tried a different doctype, and there is no difference. What am I missing? Please help. Here is the code for my HTML page right now. I am just trying to make it work, hence the sample pictures and video.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ayana Brown Wigs - Home</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->

<script type=”text/javascript” src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/crossbrowsermenu.js'></script>
<link rel=”stylesheet” href='js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css' type=”text/css” media=”screen” />
<script type=”text/javascript” src='js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js'></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

</head>

<body>
<div id="pageWrapper">
    <div id="header">
    <h1>
        <a class="header-logo" href='http://www.daniel-schuster/ayana/index.html'>Ayana Brown Wigs, Bloomington, Indiana</a>
    </h1>
    </div>

<!-- IMAGE AND VIDEO TEST ----------------->

<div class="content">
    <div class="samples">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="fancybox" rel="samples" title="Caption Test" href="images/sample.jpg"><img src="images/samplesmall.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>

        <li><a class="fancybox" rel="samples" title="Caption Test 2" href="images/sample2.jpg"><img src="images/sample2small.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>

        <li><a class="fancybox" rel="samples" title="Caption Test 3" href="images/sample3.jpg"><img src="images/sample3small.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div><br />

<div id="video">
    <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" title='Drop City Yacht Club - "Crickets"' href='http://www.youtube.com/embed/F95RD4wGpdc'><img src='images/drop-city-yacht-club.jpg' alt="drop city" /></a>
</div>

</div> <!-- End of Content -->

</div> <!-- End of contentWrapper -->

</div> <!-- End of pageWrapper -->

<script type=”text/javascript”>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(“.fancybox”).fancybox({
            width : ’70%’,
            height : ’70%’
        });
    $(“a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']“).fancybox();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seriously. Stop using a word document editor to edit your code. The magic quotes are killing you slowly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dreaded curly quotes are your problem. You have quotes that look like this:

## ”

JavaScript does not understand those. Change them to straight quotes:

## "

Your apostrophes have the same problem.

Comment: And there is no need to call fancybox twice. I'd say, remove this line: `$(“a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']“).fancybox();` since the `$(“.fancybox”).fancybox({ etc` part will take care of it.

Comment: I didn't realize that Notepad++ adds in the curly quotes. I went back into regular Notepad, switched out the curly quotes, and sure enough, that did it. That's a load off my back! Thanks a bunch for the help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have edited this code in something other than a proper script program like dashcode etc as there are a few syntax errors..

Here try this instead...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        width : '70%',
        height : '70%'
    });
$("a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']").fancybox();
});
</script>
```